# Floating on few blocks in wide content space

Tags: css, css-float

For my current project, i have to float few blocks to the left. My content block is 720px wide, while the blocks in are 350px width. But somewhy they arent floating each other. SOme of them does, some not. To each block i added rule float:left. I would float them with my hand, but i dont know the order of blocks, so cant predict how will it looks;
Here is screenshot of how does it looks now: http://d.pr/i/OKpc

Comment: here is temporary homepage http://stagealpha.dyndns.org/plasma/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there are a couple different solutions here. First, you could use some modern selectors to add `clear: left` to every even-numbered block:

```
.block-views:nth-child(2n+1) { clear: left; }
```

This will not work in Internet Explorer 8 or less.

The next solution involves adding an extra div with `clear: both` after every second block:

HTML:

```
<div class="block block-views">...</div>
<div class="block block-views">...</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="block block-views">...</div>
<div class="block block-views">...</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="block block-views">...</div>
<div class="block block-views">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Comment: here is how it looks after .block-views:nth-child(2n) { clear: left; } http://d.pr/i/yUpN

Comment: Thank you very much, im not sure if i need this project to work in ie, but for temporary fix, this'll work. You saved me alot of time.